# Removing items from a ListBox in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two `ListBox1` and `ListBox2`. I have inserted items into a `ListBox2` with the following code by selecting `ListBox1` item:

```
da6 = New SqlDataAdapter("select distinct(component_type) from component where   component_name='" & ListBox1.SelectedItem() & "'", con)
da6.Fill(ds6, "component")
For Each row As DataRow In ds6.Tables(0).Rows
    ListBox2.Items.Add(row.Field(Of String)("component_type"))
Next
```

But when I reselect another item of `ListBox1` then `ListBox2` shows preloaded items and now loaded item together.
I want only now loaded item to be displayed in listbox.
I used this code but problem not solved:

```
For i =0 To ListBox2.items.count - 1
    ListBox2.Items.removeAt(i)
Next
```

OR
`listbox2.items.clear()` is also not working..

How can I clear all items in the `ListBox2`?

Answer (score 9):

Use simply:

```
ListBox2.Items.Clear()
```

- To take your last edit into account: Do that **before** you add the new items

MSDN: [`ListBox.ObjectCollection.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.clear.aspx)

> Removes all items from the collection.

Note that the problem with your approach is that [`RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat.aspx) changes the index of all remaining items.

> When you remove an item from the list, the **indexes change for
>   subsequent items** in the list. All information about the removed item
>   is deleted. You can use this method to remove a specific item from the
>   list by specifying the index of the item to remove from the list. To
>   specify the item to remove instead of the index to the item, use the
>   Remove method. **To remove all items from the list, use the Clear
>   method**.

If you want to use `RemoveAt` anyway, you can go backwards, for example with:

a `for`-loop:

```
For i As Int32 = ListBox2.Items.Count To 0 Step -1
    ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(i)
Next
```

or  a `while`

```
While ListBox2.Items.Count > 0
    ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox2.Items.Count - 1)
End While
```

<strike>old C# code</strike>

```
for (int i = ListBox2.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(i);

while(ListBox2.Items.Count > 0)
    ListBox2.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox2.Items.Count - 1);
```

Comment: Note that the property that contain the items is `Items`

Comment: @user1945423: Sorry, i've switched the language in my answer since i'm currently using (and testing) in C# ;) Edited my answer.

Comment: Then how do I Add in the listbox from dataset and Clear Items from Listbox

Comment: @user1945423: I assume that you have first added the new items from the newly selected item and then removed all items. Of course that will not work. You need to clear frist all items from the ListBox and then add the new items.

Comment: @Tim Schmelter  yes I did That But When i reselect another item then listbox2 shows the previous loaded item and now loaded item

Answer (score 5):

This code worked for me:

ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to clear the list box, you should use the Clear ([winforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.clear.aspx) | [wpf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.clear.aspx) | [asp.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.clear.aspx)) method:

```
ListBox2.Items.Clear()
```

Comment: Then how do I Add  in the listbox from dataset and Clear Items from Listbox

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple method for deleting selected items, and all these people are going for a hard method:

```
lstYOURVARIABLE.Items.Remove(lstYOURVARIABLE.SelectedItem)
```

I used this in Visual Basic mode on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code I came up with to remove items selected by a user from a listbox It seems to work ok in a multiselect listbox (selectionmode prop is set to multiextended).:

```
Private Sub cmdRemoveList_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdRemoveList.Click
    Dim knt As Integer = lstwhatever.SelectedIndices.Count
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To knt - 1
        lstwhatever.Items.RemoveAt(lstwhatever.SelectedIndex)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Already tested by me, it works fine

```
For i =0 To ListBox2.items.count - 1
ListBox2.Items.removeAt(0)
Next
```

Comment: It removes whole listbox :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your ListBox already clear with ListBox2.Items.Clear(). The problem is that you also need to clear your dataset from previous results with ds6.Tables.Clear().

Add this in your code:

```
da6 = New SqlDataAdapter("select distinct(component_type) from component where   component_name='" & ListBox1.SelectedItem() & "'", con)
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()    ' clears ListBox1
    ListBox2.Items.Clear()    ' clears ListBox2
    ds6.Tables.Clear()        ' clears DataSet  <======= DON'T FORGET TO DO THIS
da6.Fill(ds6, "component")
For Each row As DataRow In ds6.Tables(0).Rows
    ListBox2.Items.Add(row.Field(Of String)("component_type"))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
Private Sub listbox_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) 
        Handles listbox.MouseDoubleClick
        listbox.Items.RemoveAt(listbox.SelectedIndex.ToString())
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be also checked. Selected item from the list can be deleted using for loop, but error occurs as soon as list item removed to avoid this problem just jump from the loop and start fresh selected list to be remove.

```
Private Sub BtnDelete_ClickButtonArea(Sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles BtnDelete.ClickButtonArea
        If LstTest.SelectedIndex > -1 Then
jmp1:
            If LstTest.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
                For i = 0 To LstTest.SelectedItems.Count - 1
                    For Each SI In LstTest.SelectedItems
                        LstTest.Items.Remove(SI)
                        GoTo jmp1
                    Next
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   Dim ca As Integer = ListBox1.Items.Count().ToString
    While Not ca = 0
        ca = ca - 1
        ListBox1.Items.RemoveAt(ca)
    End While
```

Comment: This is the same code that don't work by OP. Have you tried it?

Comment: You're returning a ToString() for an integer?

Comment: @Bujutsu It's not the same code, because the iteration direction is different.