# Remove line from text file which listed in list box

Tags: vb.net

I have a text file(its hosts file)
I can add lines(domains) to the file through a text box.
When i click the 'Save' button, inputted value(domain) saves to the text(hosts) file with a 127.0.0.1 prefix. At the same time it shows that in a list box too(while showing it in list box, it won't show the prefix(127.0.0.1). It'll only show the value got from the text field)

What i need now is that,

When i click and select an item from the list box and press 'Remove' button, it needs to be removed from both the list box and the text(hosts) file.

Also, while removing the selected item from the list box, the prefix(127.0.0.1) also should be removed from the file without leaving an empty line.

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCustomDomainremove.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        Dim delLine As Integer = 1
        Dim lines As List(Of String) = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts").ToList
        lines.RemoveAt(delLine - 1)
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts", lines)
        MessageBox.Show("URL removed from Block List !", "Custom Block List")
End Sub
```

Above code it removes the top value from file and selected one from list box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing items from a ListBox in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14379438/removing-items-from-a-listbox-in-vb-net)

Comment: Thank you so much guys (patel, Mary and banf) for helping me to solve the problem. All the solutions are working for me.

Comment: It is helpful for those who search later for you to mark one answer as accepted by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. Glad it is working.

Answer (score 1):

```
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lines As List(Of String) = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts").ToList
    Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts")
    Dim Lookfor As String = CStr("127.0.0.1" + ListBox1.SelectedItem)

    If lines.Contains(Lookfor) Then
        For i = 0 To Findstring.Length - 1
            lines.Remove(Lookfor)
        Next
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts", lines)
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        MessageBox.Show("URL removed from Block List !", "Custom Block List")
    Else
        MsgBox("string not found")
    End If
End Sub
```

This code works for me, you might have to tweak it slightly to match your prefereneces however, it seems to find each occurunce (if there's more than one) of the selected item in `listbox1` (if there's only one occurance you can remove the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you banf. I was worried about that exception. You handled it very well. The code is working perfectly for me. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Reading and Writing the file on every change to the list, save the list when the form closes. Read the file when the form opens and populate the list. While the form is open just add and remove list items as you normally would.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim path = "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt"
    Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(path)
    'Substring(9) the characters in "127.0.0.1" are index 0-8 so we begin with index 9
    'and return the rest of the string.
    Dim TrimmedList = From line In lines
                      Select line.Substring(9)
    For Each item In TrimmedList
        ListBox2.Items.Add(item)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    For Each item In ListBox2.Items
        sb.AppendLine("127.0.0.1" & item.ToString)
    Next
    Dim path = "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt"
    File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString)
End Sub
```

Requires

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
```

Comment: I didn't think of this idea. Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCustomDomainremove.Click
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        Dim details As String = ""
        For Each o As Object In ListBox1.Items
            details += o.ToString + vbNewLine
        Next
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts", details, False)
        MessageBox.Show("URL removed from Block List !", "Custom Block List")
End Sub
```